# how can I extract recurly account management url into my e-commerce website?

Tags: api, subscription, account, recurly

I am using recurly (recurly.com) to run a subscription business, we need to extract the customer account management url and put it into our website so the customers can manage subscriptions by themselves.  Can anyone give me some advice about how to use recurly API to realize this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an account, the hosted login token (which is used to build this URL on your side), is returned in the success response. It looks like this:

```
<hosted_login_token>71c122cb16fc90252ff845eacf5d7814</hosted_login_token>
```

At any time, you can also do a GET request on the account details to obtain the login. It is recommended, however, that you store this value locally as soon as the account is created, so you are not constantly polling the API.

See https://dev.recurly.com/docs/create-an-account for more details.